# I am not getting all the facebook photos user was tagged in

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using facebook graph I am fetching user photos. Later I will shorten this with a simple if statement to filter only a friend who was tagged in that photo.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=MYACCESS_TOKEN.

But I am not getting all the photos that user was tagged in. I tagged 11 photos in friends alubms and he tagged me in 9 photos.

We are getting only 9 photos, the remaining photo was not even coming in JSON as output via the graph.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var aToken = document.getElementById('aToken').value;
    jQuery.getJSON(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='+aToken,
        function(data) {
            fbid = jQuery('#fbid').val();
            data = data.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if(data[i].from.id == fbid || data[i].tags.data.id == fbid || data[i].tags.data[0].id == fbid) {
                    jQuery('#photos').append( "<div style='float:left;margin:25px;'><a href='crop.php?url="+data[i].source+"'><img src='"+data[i].picture+"'/></a></div>");
                }
            }
            if (jQuery('#photos').html() == "") {
                jQuery('#photos').hide();
                jQuery('#upload').show();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Here `fbid` is my friends facebook id. Is Facebook limiting the photos or is it a problem with my code?

Comment: you're not getting the photos from the albums
see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538638/not-getting-all-the-photos-user-is-tagged-in-facebook/10668919#10668919

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you fully. Are you tagged in the 11 photos of your friends pictures or have you tagged him in 11 pictures? Your api call

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
```

is only selecting photos that have you tagged in them. Which means if you are only tagged in 9, that is the amount you will receive back.

Comment: i tagged him in my picture, i need both the 11+9 photos in it

Comment: Then I think you will have to make multiple queries to the graph api. That call only brings back your photos. You will then need to make a call such as graph.facebook.com/YOUR-FRIENDS-ID/photos and merge all the photos. I'm not sure if there's a way you could combine this in 1 call with an FQL query

Comment: In fact you can. So your query would be something similar to

graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT src FROM photo WHERE pid in ( SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject in(id1,id2) )

That will then give you the src of all the photos in question. Here's info on the fields you can select

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

and you can test out queries here  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and bear in mind you would need to grant the app the proper permissions

Comment: i tried explorer and cheked json data i am not getting the photo.Do facebook restrict private alubm's photos.

Comment: Yeah, if your app doesn't have the required permissions, or the users privacy settings prevent you from viewing those photos then you won't be able to do it. You could try using your Applications access token rather than your users. You can test that out in the explorer by checking the graph api explorer drop down and selecting your app. Also check you have enabled the "friends photos" permission by clicking the "get access token" button in the app

Answer (score 0):

What reason do you have for thinking the other two ('missing') photos should be visible in the API call? the user who uploaded the photos has privacy settings which will affect whether the photos can be accessed like this

Answer (score 0):

you're not getting the photos from the albums.
you should get a list of the albums, and use the graph/album-number/photos call..
there's an example for iphone here:

[Not getting all the photos user is tagged in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538638/not-getting-all-the-photos-user-is-tagged-in-facebook/10668919#10668919)

hope that helps